# Why does the runat-attribute in the head-tag change the way meta tags are handled in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Example 1:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="description" content="<%= Foo %>"/>
</head>
```

Renders

```
<meta http-equiv="description" content="Bar"/>
```

Example 2:

```
<head runat="server">
  <meta http-equiv="description" content="<%= Foo %>"/>
</head>
```

Renders:

```
<meta http-equiv="description" content="&lt;%= Foo %>"/>
```

Note the discrepancy, the `<` has become `&lt;` but the `>` remains the same.

There are [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417510/edit-html-meta-tag-w-asp-net) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873880/trouble-print-meta-tags-with-asp-net-mvc) on this topic, and the answers are the workarounds, but nobody seems to know why this happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a script tag (<% = %>) inside a server control, that's why it's turned into plain text instead of being executed.

You can add the meta tag from the code behind like this:

```
HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();
meta.HttpEquiv = "description";
meta.Content = Foo;
Page.Header.Controls.Add(meta);
```

Comment: But <title><%= "Hello, world!" %></title> does work in a head tag with the runat attribute set to "server"

Comment: Title can be controlled through Page.Title as it is.

Answer (score 1):

When you add runat=server the Head tag becomes a server control. I guess based on your results that the contents of server controls are not parsed for inline substitutions using the <% ... %> syntax.

You could make the Meta tag a server control as well by adding the runat=server to it and access its attributes programmatically.