# Scriptlet is not working in head tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add version number to CSS files for production environment not to force user every time press Ctrl+F5 to download new CSS files after new version is deployed in prod server as the old version is cached in browser.

I'm adding build number as querystring param like this.

```
link href="Styles/jquery.Autocomplete.css?<%= Globals.BuildNumber %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
```

but the output is this

```
link href="../../Styles/jquery.Autocomplete.css?&lt;%= Globals.BuildNumber %>"
```

Looks that scriptlet is not working in head tag, as this is fine in body tag.

Comment: This is a bizarre way of doing Cache management, why not simply use `Cache-Control: max-age=0` and/or `Cache-Control: no-cache` directives to expire the client cache and use `Last-Modified` to update the files.?

Comment: It is weird however that your scriptlet is not working can you post the two examples (the one that works vs. one that doesn't) ? it feels as if there may be a silly typo there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `runat="server"` attribute (It escapes the `href` string) from `<head>` tag.

```
<head >
    <title></title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="Styles/jquery.Autocomplete.css?<%= Globals.BuildNumber %>" .. />
</head>
```

but this is not a single (and probably not good) solution. (for more info [read article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210422200927/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051006-1.aspx)). No need to remove `runat="server"` attribute if you can write this code:

OR use `HtmlLink` (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls namespace)

```
myHtmlLink.Href = "Styles/jquery.Autocomplete.css?" + Globals.BuildNumber;
myHtmlLink.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
myHtmlLink.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");

Header.Controls.Add(myHtmlLink);
```

Comment: Are you sure?  I've definitely written code doing this with a runat="server" in the head section

Comment: ???  Nothing's wrong, I'm just pretty sure scriptlets will still work in the head if it has runat="server"

Comment: @AdamRackis - Have a look at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904361/why-does-the-runat-attribute-in-the-head-tag-change-the-way-meta-tags-are-handle

Comment: I wonder if OP's original `link` tags had runat="server" on them.  That would explain it.  Because I've written code that I'm looking at now that uses `link href='<%= blah %>' inside of a head with runat="server" on it

Answer (score 1):

It's not documented anywhere, but as you've found out it doesn't appear that [HtmlHead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd56933s.aspx) supports [embedded code blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Here's one way to get around that. (if it's not obvious, it should go in your code-behind file):

```
const int BuildNumber = 1;
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
  base.OnLoad(e);
// add style sheet
  Header.Controls.Add(new Literal() {
    Text = string.Format(
      @"<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='custom.css?{0}' />",
      BuildNumber
    )
  });
}
```