# favicon not rendering properly from ASP.Net master page

Tags: asp.net

```
<link href="<%=this.faviconURL %>" type="image/x-icon" rel="icon" />
```

It will literally print out '

```
<link href="%3C%25=this.faviconURL%20%25%3E" type="image/x-icon" rel="icon" />
```

It's as if the runtime is taking the link tag literally and refusing to do any sort of substitution.  Can someone explain why this is happening?  I would really prefer not using web controls for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add `runat` to link tag. So It can be processed by Asp.Net.

```
<link href="<%=this.faviconURL %>" runat="server" type="image/x-icon" rel="icon" />
```

Apperantly I was wrong see [Scriptlet is not working in head tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613083/scriptlet-is-not-working-in-head-tag) and you can simple use without runat tag.

```
<link href="~/server/icofileurl"   type="image/x-icon" rel="icon" />
```

[How to add favicon.ico in ASP.NET site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963584/how-to-add-favicon-ico-in-asp-net-site?lq=1)

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using a web control, but it does seem to be the shortest route to success in this case.  I would really like to understand *why* this limitation exists though.